# Windows Phone Application Resources

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, resourcedictionary

I've added resource to App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>      
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml"/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But when I start the application it crashed with unspecified error.
And thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Check that generic.xaml is in your root dir. Also check that there are no errors in generic.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur code seems to be alright.
in ur code--->

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml"/>
```

might be there is some path error `"Generic.xaml"` , are u sure this Generic.xaml file is in ur root directory. or it should be `"someFolder/Generic.xaml"` ?

Comment: Firstly it was in Themes folder, but I've changed it to root to check if it will work.

Comment: And it's in root folder, I've double checked it

Comment: I've figured it out. The exception occurs, because of I forgot to add converter to the page. Thank you!